# How to parse duration format from duration in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, simpledateformat, date-format

I have a duration format which is like **0DT3H10M**. So need to know how to parse this kind of data.

I want 0 Days 3 Hours and 10 Minutes from **0DT3H10M**

in a specific format.

We can manually parse it by a character which is working fine but is there any other way or library available for this in android/java?

Comment: Is that a date format? The end looks like the time 3:10, delimited by H and M, but I don't see anything date-ish in there.

Comment: You need to make your own parser, I think.

Comment: Post here more examples of these dates. The one you've posted isn't enough to build a parser.

Comment: You can create a regex pattern and match the string accordingly.

Comment: It’s probably a duration: 0 days 3 hours 10 minutes. Append a `P` in front, and `Duration` parses it.

Comment: Indeed that looks just like a ISO 8601 duration format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Duration

I will guess that string represents a duration of three hours and ten minutes.

Unfortunately that string fails to comply with the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) used by default in the *java.time* classes `Duration` and `Period`. The standard starts all such strings with a `P`. And the standard separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds with a `T`. So your input of three hours and ten minutes would be `PT3H10M`.

You will need to parse the string with your own code. Then use the extracted values to set the value of a `java.time.Duration` object.

You may be able to get away with simply prepending a `P` to comply with the standard. I hesitate to recommend this only because you would need to see the range of possible values you might receive to verify this approach would work.

```
Duration.parse( "P" + "0DT3H10M" )
```

Tip: Educate the publisher of your input data about ISO 8601.

Comment: Many thanks Basil for the answer but i am integration this in android and this call requires API level 26 so i can not use this approach.

Comment: @MohitDholakia Yes you can. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects. Covered on many other Questions and Answers.